# How to optimize reading from a large file in a while loop in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I was going through some random articles on the internet on how to optimize file input to a loop and tried to test things myself. They claim that file descriptor manipulation in most cases can be fast and efficient than directly reading from file into a loop. I tried to test it doing this:

First read from the file directly into the loop:

```
time while read a ; do :;done < testfile
```

The time this command took to run is:

```
real 0m8.782s
user 0m1.292s
sys  0m0.399s
```

Now I try to do some file-descriptor manipulation as one of the article suggested as this:

1. I first redirect file -descriptor zero to a file-descriptor 3 like: `exec 3<&0`
2. I then redirect testfile to file descriptor 0 : `exec 0 < testfile`
3. And at the end of loop I'm reading the data as `0<&3` which would mean redirect file-descriptor `3` to `0`. So the complete line is as below:

   ```
   exec 3<&0;exec 0<testfile; time for i in $(seq 1 20);do while read a; do :;done; done; exec 0<&3
   ```

This gives me a time as:

```
     real 0m8.792s
     user 0m1.258s
     sys  0m0.430s
```

But I see the time to be almost same in both cases, in fact a tad bit slower when I use file descriptors. The file `testfile` is `6MB` with close to `400k` lines each with `20-25` characters max.

In fact for even bigger files, the direct read from files is actually faster than the file descriptor manipulation.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: @jww : I absolutely don't agree with your comment. My question is very direct. I have even put in the working output of how I have tested things. This is a Q&A site helping developers. It is very unfortunate that people like you are more critical about how a question needs to be framed (until and unless the question absolutely vague which in this case is not), rather than giving explanatory answers and helping community members.

Comment: Please remove the image and post the code as text.  Then please explain at each step what you are doing.  I don't think most people know what `exec 3<&0` is, just as one example.  It isn't very clear to us what you think you are showing with these one-liners, nor what you would like us to answer.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I removed the image and tried to make the question more explanatory. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use C. This is the fastest you can get and if you really care about speed.

You can write you own program to `getline()` from input stream and then call `system` on each line. This may be slower because of the `fork()` and `exec()` calls, but may be way faster if you can put your line operations into C code.
You can write your own shell builtin. Shells `read` builting just calls `read()`, browse bash [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/read.def#n583). You can write your own shell builtin which loops a command through input faster then the default `read` builtin. like `my_read_bultin 'file' -- 'command to run on each line'`.

To make you post reproducible I created a big file:

```
$ for ((i=0;i<1200000;++i)); do echo ${RANDOM}; done >/tmp/1
$ du -hs /tmp/1
6.5M    /tmp/1
```

Then run:

```
$ time ( printf '#include<errno.h>\n#include<stdlib.h>\n#include<stdio.h>\nint main(){char*b=0;size_t n=0;ssize_t r;while((r=getline(&b,&n,stdin))>0);if(errno)abort();return 0;}\n' | gcc -Ofast -Wall -xc -o/tmp/a.out -; /tmp/a.out </tmp/1; )
real    0m0.095s
user    0m0.064s
sys 0m0.031s
$ time ( cat >/dev/null; ) </tmp/1
real    0m0.007s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.006s
$ time ( while read l; do :; done </tmp/1; )
real    0m6.994s
user    0m5.222s
sys 0m1.731s
$ time ( exec 3</tmp/1; while read -u3 l; do :; done; )
real    0m7.953s
user    0m5.965s
sys 0m1.949s
$ time xargs -a /tmp/1 -n1 true
< very, very slow, got impatient and CTRL+C it >
```